# Optimitze Table, MyIsam

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, myisam

I was reading a post on Percona (https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/12/09/mysql-optimize-tables-innodb-stop/) that said dropping and adding an index on a innodb table was almost 20* faster than using the table optimize syntax. Is this also true for myisam tables?

I have a 50 million row table and am deleting about 40k rows a day from it (while also adding in 50k new rows).

Comment: Just wondering why you are still using MyISAM? It's now deprecated! Do you have a compelling reason  not to convert your tables to InnoDB?

Comment: @Vérace Went through about 10 iterations of creating the same table in innodb and every variation performed worse.

Comment: How much worse?

Comment: Considerably. Some queries took +50 minutes in the innodb format, vs. 2 minutes in myisam. Percona said `This causing heavy consumption for RAM bandwidth and CPU cycles. The table is smaller in myisam format and you can get faster results if large_table will be converted back to myisam.` so we've kept in myisam. We have reduced the table by 40 million rows recently though so I might benchmark it again though.

Comment: Have you tried [file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-enabling.html)? Just a thought...

Comment: Yes, that is/was enabled.

Comment: @user3783243 - There are many subtle reasons why blindly changing from MyISAM to InnoDB can lead to performance declines that can be rectified.  Some are discussed [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).  Please start a new Question to get to the bottom of it.  Start with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the table size, amount of RAM, and settings used for `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: @Vérace - I would not expect `innodb_file_per_table` to make _any_ difference in performance.  It's main utility relates to returning disk space to the OS.

Comment: @RickJames The innodb kind of went off topic. The question is if the myisam also should use the drop/re-create or if the performance issue is only present on innodb tables and `optimize` functions fine on myisam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Some of this is off-topic.)

**Fast ALTER**

- The handling of ADD/DROP INDEX is different for MyISAM and InnoDB.
- Oracle is focusing *only* on InnoDB.
- InnoDB can allow writes while an index is being built -- by keeping track of what needs to be added to the index.  It already has a "Change Buffer" to optimize such.  MyISAM would have to invent a similar mechanism, and has no 'transaction' hooks to help.

Therefore, I conclude that all(?) benefits from `ALTER TABLE ... INLINE/INPLACE` are handled inside the InnoDB engine, leaving MyISAM out in the cold.

Long ago, *one* flavor of online `ALTER TABLE`, namely adding a item to an `ENUM` (with restrictions), was implemented.  But that only required modifying the `.frm` file.

**OPTIMIZE**

In one situation in a hundred, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is useful in MyISAM.  The need for `OPTIMIZE` in InnoDB is much *less* frequent.

One example (applies to MyISAM only):  The table has a lot of churn -- either from `UPDATEs` that change the lengths of rows or from `DELETE`+`INSERT`.  MyISAM's `INSERT` gives preference to filling in holes in the `.MYD`, which can lead to individual rows scattered across multiple disk blocks.  This slows down `SELECT`, even for 'point queries'.

**Time Series**

Are you are deleting "old" rows and adding "new" rows?  If so,

- Your MyISAM may need `OPTIMIZE`, as explained above.  But, with InnoDB, `OPTIMIZE` would be mostly a waste.
- `DELETEing` 40M rows locks a MyISAM table for a long time.
- There are [*other techniques*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) to deal with big deletes.

**Partitioning for time series**

- `PARTITIONing`, even with MyISAM (*before MySQL 8.0*), is possible.  It might let you turn the time consuming `DELETE` into an instantaneous `DROP PARTITION`.  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)
- Using `PARTITIONing` would probably obviate the need for `OPTIMIZE`, even for MyISAM.
- Caveat:  Usually when adding partitioning, all the indexes need rethinking.